# For what values of $x$ is the function $f(x)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{x^t}{x^t-1}$ ($ x\ge 0$) discontinuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

> Define the function 
>   $$
> f(x)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{x^t}{x^t-1},\quad x\ge 0.
> $$
>   For what values of $x$ is $f$ discontinuous?

Attempt:

Rewrite $f$ as 
$$
f(x)=\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{x^t}{x^t-1}=\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x^t-1}\right)$$

And play with right term:

1. When $0\le x<1$ ,  $\dfrac{1}{x^t-1}$ goes to $-1$ since $x^t\to 0$
2. When $x=1$, $\dfrac{1}{x^t-1}$ undefined  so it is discontiunity point
3. When $1<x$, $\dfrac{1}{x^t-1}$ goes to $0$ since $x^t\to \infty$

Can we say that only discontinous point is $x=1$? But I have a problem because $f(x)$ is a bit strangely defined. When we take $t\to \infty $ after putting $x$ right? And Should I concern 
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)
=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{x^t}{x^t-1}
$$ in more detail?

I don't feel so good about this limit process in this problem. How should we approach this kind of questions?

Comment: at $x=1$ the function is not defined, so it is meaningless to ask by the continuity of $f$ at that point

Comment: What you have done is right. When you can compute $f(x)$ for each explicitly why go back to the original definition and worry about double limits?

Answer (score 2):

We have:

1. $f$ is not defined in $x=1$.
2. $f(x)=0$, if $0 \le x<1$.
3. $f(x)=1$, if $x>1$.

Conclusion: $f$ is continuous on $[0, \infty) \setminus \{1\}.$